# file path cannot be found by the server

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help me with this. i have uploaded a program and a database online. In my program i have a report that can be downloaded. this report has picture on it. This is my problem.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File /images/photo.PNG not found!' in /home/content/20/7559320/html/war/PHPExcel/Worksheet/Drawing.php:227
>
> Stack trace: #0 /home/content/20/7559320/html/war/admin_report1.php(178): PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing->setPath('/images/photo.P...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/content/20/7559320/html/war/PHPExcel/Worksheet/Drawing.php on line 227

what should i put in the database table for the file path be valid?

Comment: windows/linux? Where is the PHP that generates this error?

Comment: You're trying to use a web path (e.g. a url path yhou'd find in an http request to your site) as a file-system path. URL space generally has very little (if any) relationship to paths on your file system. You need to at LEAST insert the site's document root into your request, so it becomes /path/to/doc/root/images/photo.PNG

Comment: i have try  the format you suggest @MarcB but it doesnt work to.

Comment: well, we have NO deals about how your site's file structure is set up, so we can't really help you. you need to figure out what the path is.

Comment: can you suggest any standard file path format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/home/content/20/7559320/html/` is your site's document root and the `photo.PNG` file you're trying to load is actually in `/home/content/20/7559320/html/images/`, try this

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/../images/photo.PNG';

$someExcelDrawingObject->setPath($path);
// I don't know what your PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing object variable is called of course
```

Where `__DIR__` resolves to the absolute filesystem path of the current PHP script (`admin_report1.php => /home/content/20/7559320/html/war`).

If your image is actually in `/home/content/20/7559320/html/war/images/`, the path would be

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/images/photo.PNG';
```